# div doesn't center when browser is smaller than min-width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div. The div has a width of 400pt, the body has a width of at least 500pt, to leave a space of min. 50pt around the div. My code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <style>
        body{
            min-width:500pt;    
        }

        #centered{
            position:absolute;
            background-color:#ff0000;
            width:400pt;
            left:calc(50% - 200pt);
            height:400pt;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="centered"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As long as the width of the browser is greater than `min-width`, everything works fine:
[image: width > min-width]

But as soon as the width of the Browser gets smaller than `min-width`, and a scrollbar appears at the bottom, the div is only centered in the space you see, when the scrollbar is on the left, but not centered in the middle of the whole (scrollable) body:
[image: width < min-width]
Is there a way to fix this problem?

*If you don't understand my problem, feel free to ask.*

Comment: pt is not for the screen but for print. You should use px, em or other measures.

Comment: I'mn not sure if I understand the question but try this css: #centered{ width:400pt; height:height:400pt; background-color:#ff0000; margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: I don't get why you have the min-width on the body. That is why the box isn't centered. You are forcing the body into that width and 50% calculation is based on that width so it is going to be off-center when you resize the window to be less than the min-width of the body. Just remove the min-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a min-width for your body, just add this

```
#centered{   
max-width: 400px;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: red;
   display: block;
   margin: 100px auto;
}
```

If it doesn't work for you feel free to comment :)

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<style>
    #centered{
        position:absolute;
        background-color:#ff0000;
        width:400pt;
        left:calc(50% - 200pt);
        height:400pt;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500pt){
        #centered{
            width:100%;
            left:0px;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="centered">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Same problem occurs.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to remove body style. Code is edited again and works.